# orders of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Not really sure how to go about this in general terms, for example: say you have a group $G$ containing $a$ and $b$ such that $a\cdot b=b \cdot a$. Show that if $a$ has order $m$ in and $b$ has order $n$ ($\in \mathbb{N}$), and $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $a \cdot b$ has order $mn$.

Comment: Hi SFL, it looks like your question might be closed soon.  It would help if you gave us some more context to this question.  For example: if you don't know how to answer this in general terms, do you have any thoughts on how to answer this in "specific terms"?  It would also help if you formatted your math correctly; see [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360).

Answer (score 0):

If $(ab)^k=1$, then $a^k = b^{-k}$.

Now $o(a^k)$ divides $o(a)=m$ and $o(b^{-k})$ divides $o(b)=n$.

Therefore, $o(a^k)$ divides $\gcd(m,n)=1$, and so $a^k=1$.
This implies that $k$ is a multiple of $m$.

Also, $b^{-k}=1$ implies that $k$ is a multiple of $n$.

Since $\gcd(m,n)=1$, we must have that $k$ is a multiple of $mn$.

Since $(ab)^{mn}=1$, the order of $ab$ is $mn$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
(ab)^k = a^kb^k
$$
for all integers $k$.  Use this to show that $(ab)^k = e$ if and only if $k$ is a multiple of the orders of both $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $a$ has order $m$ (we denote $o(a) = m$) and $o(b) = n$. We have that 
$$(ab)^{mn} = \underbrace{ab \cdot ab \cdot \ldots \cdot ab}_{mn \text{ times}}$$
and since $ab = ba$ in the group $G$, we can put all $a$'s in the front and all $b$'s in the back, so we find that 
$$(ab)^{mn} = a^{mn}b^{mn} = (a^m)^n(b^m)^n = 1$$
where $1$ is the neutral element in your group $G$. This proves that $ab$ has finite order. Hence we have that $o(ab) = k$ for some non zero natural number $k$. From this, we find that $k \mid mn$.

Because we have that $(ab)^k = 1$ and $ab = ba$, we have that $a^k = b^{-k}$ and $b^k = a^{-k}$. Hence we also find the following equalities:
$$(a^k)^n = (b^{-k})^n = (b^n)^{-k} = 1$$
and hence we must have that $m \mid kn$, since the order of $a$ is $m$. Analogously, we can show that we must have that $n \mid km$. Since $\text{gcd}(m,n) = 1$, we must have that $m \mid k$ and $n \mid k$, hence $mn \mid k$. Therefore, we have that $k = mn$, so $o(ab) = mn$.